# Initializing char * is not giving error

Tags: c++, c

```
struct st{ 
int a; 
char *ptr; 
}obj; 

main()
{   
   obj.a=10;    
   obj.ptr="Hello World";          // (1) memory allocation?
   printf("%d,%s",obj.a,obj.ptr);
}
```

`ptr` is declared in struct. When the assignment of `Hello world` occurs, memory is not allotted and yet this program works fine and gives output properly. Shouldn't it fail/crash when assignment done at marker `(1)`?

Comment: Why negative votes??!!

Comment: I did not downvote, but the problem I see here is that you assign a string literal to a `char *`, not that there is no memory allocation. A `char *` can point to existing memory.

Comment: No - there is no problem - you're just initialising a pointer with the address of a string literal. You may get a warning regarding const-ness, but other than that (and the missing `int` before `main`) the code is fine.

Comment: @PaulR But isn't that allowed only at definition of char *

Comment: No - it's fine - get a book on C and read up on string literals.

Comment: Also of note, C++ answer is: use `std::string` instead of `char *` and use `std::cout` instead of `printf`, don't use global variables, etc.

Comment: @PaulR This is one point where C and C++ differ.  In C, a string literal has type `char[]`, in C++, `char const[]`.  In C++ there _was_ a (deprecated) conversion of `char const[]` to `char*`, when the `char const[]` was a string literal (and only then).  This conversion was removed in C++11, which means that in the most recent C++,  the above code shouldn't compile.

Comment: Ahha.. So much wisdom in a question with 2 down votes.. LOL!!!

Comment: @crashmstr Well written C doesn't make much use of global variables either.  (In fact, the presence of dynamic initialization of globals in C++ may mean that in some cases, they are more acceptable in C++ than in C.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"Hello World"` is a string literal residing in a read-only memory section (.rodata) of your program. You point to this section then print the contents. The program behavior is 100% well-defined and should not crash.

It is however good practice to always declare pointers to string literals as `const char*`, because you are not allowed to modify string literals.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly valid.

At compile time (minus compiler optimizations), they are placed in the text/rodata segment of the code. Not sure if you are familiar with the layout of an executable in memory (also known as the runtime environment), but you have the Text, Data, BSS, Heap and Stack.

like

```
  obj.ptr="Hello World";
```

will place `Hello World` in the read-only parts of the memory and making   `obj.ptr` a pointer to that, making any writing operation on this memory illegal.

It has no name and has static storage duration (meaning that it lives for the entire life of the program); and a variable of type pointer-to-char, called   `obj.ptr`, which is initialised with the location of the first character in that unnamed, read-only array.

At runtime, the char pointer is allocated on the stack and is first set to point to the area in memory where the string `Hello World` is.

Answer (score 1):

First, the answer differs somewhat depending on the language (C
or C++), and in the case of C++, the version of the standard.
In both cases, however, `"Hello World" is a string literal: in
C, it has type`char [12]`, and in C++, type`char const [12]`,
and the array has static lifetime, so exists for the lifetime of
the program.

In C, when you assign it to a `char*`, you have the standard
array to pointer conversion; in C++ pre-C++11, you have
a deprecated `char const[]` to `char*` conversion, which is only
valid if the `char const[]` is a string literal—the
compiler should warn; in C++11, the conversion is illegal, and
your program shouldn't compile (but I'm willing to bet that it
will for many years hence).

Answer (score 0):

my compiler (g++ 4.7.2) throws a warning:

`warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]`

If you don't get this warning, you can try to pass `-Wall` to your compiler (imo always a good idea)

Comment: For some reason this is tagged both C and C++... In C, string literals are of type `char*`. In C++ they are of type `const char*`. In both languages you should regard them as `const char*`.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question - it should be a comment at most.

Answer (score -2):

When you're assigning a string literal to a char pointer you're not assigned memory !
All it does is searching a part of the memory for the string, if it is found - it points to the start of it - if it is not found it creates it. Either way - no memory is assigned and the pointer turns into a constant (read-only) - just try and see you can't change it as it is a constant in memory - Sometimes it's good if you don't want to change that string and sometimes it's not - depends on what you want to do :)